# I want to access four FASTA files, to print organism name from header line?

Tags: regex, perl, file-handling

I tried it but it doesnt show any errors or warnings and output too??I need to print organism name from header line or first line of these FASTA files..

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar=("seq.fasta","sequ.fasta","sequence.fasta","sq.fasta");
for(my $i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
   my $afile=$ar[$i];
   open(FH,'<',"$afile")|| die($!);

while(my $line=<FH>)
{  
    print"$line\n";
    $line=~ m/.+?\[(.+?)\]/g;
    print"$1\n";
}
}
```

Comment: sample input (fasta file)..? what error you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure your files are not empty?

Comment: yeah.. it didnt have, that is the problem...thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programing problem, the input files are empty as said in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on question anyway I just assume the input. Just try this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @headerlines = ();
my @ar=("seq.fasta","sequ.fasta","sequence.fasta","sq.fasta");
for(my $i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    my $afile=$ar[$i];
    open(FH,'<',"$afile")|| die($!);
    while(my $line=<FH>)
    {
        push(@headerlines, "$afile-->".$1) if($line=~ m/.+?\[(.+?)\]/);
    }
}

print join "\n", @headerlines;
```

> Output:

`Filename --> organism-xxxxxxxxxxx`

`seq.fasta-->organism=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
`sequ.fasta-->organism=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
`sequence.fasta-->organism=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
`sq.fasta-->organism=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: But, why OP's code doesn't work? You just use an array instead of print within the loop.

Comment: Yeah. I know. That's why you asked OP to check the input file doesn't empty. Me too asked input file to check.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code should work with some warnings. As Toto mentioned in his comment please verify your file has the content.

You can use the condition to skip those warnings; for your code answer should be

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar=("test1.fasta","test2.fasta");

for(my $i=0;$i<=$#ar;$i++)
{
    my $afile=$ar[$i];
    open(FH,'<',"$afile")|| die($!);
    while(my $line=<FH>) 
    {  
        if($line=~ m/.+?\[(.+?)\]/){ #Make a condition to match and print it inside

            print"$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some tips and tricks.

And your are in Perl, you can the use for loop like below,

```
for my $i(0..$#ar)
{
  .. your code

}
```

In your case, you are not using the index anywhere apart from getting the filename. So iterate the loop for an array..

```
for my $afile(@ar)
{
  #  my $afile=$ar[$i]; # no need of this line
```

We all know fasta header it should present at the first line in the file. you can read the first line using the following code

```
open(FH,'<',$afile)|| die($!);
my $firstLine = scalar <FH>;
```

no need to read the full content from the file. (i.e remove the while loop)

and the final code should be

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar=("test1.fasta","test2.fasta");

for my $afile(@ar)
{
    open(FH,'<',$afile)|| die($!);
    my $line= scalar <FH>;
    $line=~ m/.+?\[(.+?)\]/;
    print"$1\n";
}
```

Comment: the files are empty ,that's whey its didn't work...sorry for the trouble..

Answer (score 0):

Verify your input files for regex pattern, otherwise it should work. I took some liberty to alter your code to following form

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use feature 'say';

my @files = qw(seq_1.fasta seq_2.fasta seq_3.fasta seq_4.fasta);

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    open FH, "< $file"
        or die "Couldn't open $file";

    map { say $1 if /.+?\[(.+?)\]/ } <FH>;

    close FH;
}
```

As no input file sample was provided I used following sample for the test

seq_1.fasta

```
somedata nothing special here
something [sequence_1] something else
well some other data here
```

seq_2.fasta

```
somedata nothing special here
something [sequence_2] something else
well some other data here
```

seq_3.fasta

```
somedata nothing special here
something [sequence_3] something else
well some other data here
```

seq_4.fasta

```
somedata nothing special here
something [sequence_4] something else
well some other data here
```

Comment: Please include at least some snippet from your fasta file with your query. Otherwise we try to solve the issue in blind as we unaware what you have in data files.